# C# WinForms program : remote server return error 429 : Too many request

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a very serous problem in c#
I write an application to send data from my local database (sql) to a web-service(php laravel mysql). I have two table (local DB) and each table contain about 2000 record of data. so my data is huge to transport and i must do it repeatedly every 1 hour.

```
foreach (var c in pdatabase.tbl_Check)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    if (c.IsActive == true)
    {
        CheckCLS ch = new CheckCLS(c, cmp.company_id, "1390", null, null);
        var list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ch);
        //string api_key = "pLED8HgjahgPt5gKvnFDYpJU6rBUYvp76zSnEhvZfqeuHk6XtxhrEsBnDZszwsPBEvqDuqSuybLkpNqhN3hgtBZZzPrmTm28wnss3KjwAuJStsgHVTdkMbPjdJ6VtguVrg3FMzXXY3X58SbEdL93YXMJctkhcavvEjMWXRKDMqf9rp5P9skNqzLyL5q5vyWcgKmfwwFMzZELyftpgFfMAK4wNwS6jYLkttg3fcCEhvJVy5w6LmKWG2NmrZep29Yq";
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.myrezume.ir/check/public/api/v1/addChecks?key=" + api_key);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(list);
            // streamWriter.Flush();
            //  streamWriter.Close();
        }
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            CheckResultCLS r = new CheckResultCLS();
            r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CheckResultCLS>(result.ToString());
        }
    }
```

here is my code
but unfortunately i am getting this stupid error over and over
as you see i put to sleep after sending each record for about one second but it didn't work and i am getting the same error
Is there any way that I can do my job?
I am despaired!

Comment: "and each table contain about 2000 record of data. so my data is huge to transport " - 2000 rows is not huge. In fact, it's TINY!

Comment: @MitchWheat
I tought its huge. why there is this stupid error again and agian

Comment: many web services restrict requests by API key. The one you are accessing appears to be no different.

Comment: @MitchWheat
actually one of my friends wrote the api, you mean the problem is apis?

Comment: The server may be some cheap hosting that throttles requests. Is it possible to send more data (multiple rows per request) instead of one at a time? Sending 500 or more rows may not be too hard, especially as you are sending them JSON.

Comment: @RonBeyer
thank you for your suggestion, i will try it